# How to specify http response order in angular js tests?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

A controller makes 2 calls to a remote http location to get data.
When data comes a procedure is called. When both requests return data, then data merging is done and some aggregation is performed.

The purpose of a unit test would be to test if the controller works as expected no matter the order of responses.

```
it("downloads all data and combines it", function() {
        ...
        $httpBackend.expectGET(responsePerDomainQuery).respond(
            { result: [ { result: 2 }, { result: 3 } ] });
        $httpBackend.expectGET(responsePerTrQuery).respond(
            { result: [{ result: 1 }, { result: 4 }] });
        $controller("Ctrl", { '$scope': $scope });
        $httpBackend.flush();
        ... some expectations ...
}
```

The test passes but it does not guarantee that any order of successfully responding requests will not break the controller's logic. How can this be achieved?

Comment: How are you making those 2 AJAX requests in your controller/service? If I had to make 2 AJAX calls together I would use something like `$q.all( [req1, req2] )` and this already guarantees that the order of the results is irrelevant for your callbacks, so no need to test this case.

Comment: I'm using 2 independent calls to $http.get(..).success(...). What is this $q.all(..)?

Comment: And still, even if you know you wrote a good controller I thing you should check that the outcome works independently of the sequence in which the async tasks finish.

Comment: It's a convenience method to deal with multiple simultaneous promises (like in your case), making sure that some code executes only when all requests are satisfied, thus making the order of their response irrelevant. A couple of links: a [short blog post](https://www.jonathanfielding.com/combining-promises-angular/) and a [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-q-all).

Comment: @Nobita: Thank you for your explanation. I may simplify my controller now. Yet a purpose of a unit test is to contract testee behaviour. In this case, you still should perform tests that check that, no matter how is the testee implemented, different response sequence will be handled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I said "no need to test this case" i was referring to the fact that using `$q.all` already guarantees that the callback is executed only when all of the requests are satisfied. That being said I agree that preparing tests for your own implementation is a good practice, so here's I would do it.

(Mind that this is just pseudo code, some things may need to be tweaked in order to work properly, but that's just to explain how i would tackle this one.)

First of all I would move my AJAX calls away from my controller and provide a dedicated service for them (maybe you already did it this way, if so that's great, bear with me for now).

As an example:

```
angular.service('myQueries', function($http){
   this.myReq1 = function(){
      return $http.get(API.url1);
   };
   this.myReq1 = function(){
      return $http.get(API.url2);
   };
});
```

Then I would test this service on its own normally using `$httpBackend.expectGET()`.

I would then get back to the controller and use that service in there as specified in my comments to the question:

```
angular.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myQueries, $q){
  // at load time query for results
  $q.all([myQueries.myReq1(), myQueries.myReq2()])
     // everything after this is guaranteed to be run ONLY when
     // both responses are in our hands
    .then(doSomethingWithBoth)
     // one or both requests went bad
     // let's handle this situation too.
    .catch(someThingWentBad);

  function doSomethingWithBoth(data){
    $scope.myData = data;
  }

  function someThingWentBad(data){
    $scope.disaster = true;
  }
});
```

At this point we can test our controller and inject a mocked service into it. Many ways to do it but something similar should do:

```
 var scope, controller, fakeService, q, dfd1, dfd2;

 beforeEach(function(){
  fakeService = {
    myReq1: function(){
      dfd1 = q.defer();
      return dfd1.promise;
    },
    myReq2: function(){
      dfd2 = q.defer();
      return dfd2.promise;
    },
   };
 })

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
    q = $q;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('myCtrl', { $scope: scope, myQueries: fakeService });
}));
```

At this point you are free to resolve/reject the promises exactly when you want. You can check what happens when the first response is faster than the second:

```
it('should do this when one response is faster', function(){
  dfd1.resolve('blabla');
  // myReq2 is still pending so doSomethingWithBoth() has not yet been called
  scope.$apply();
  expect(scope.myData).toBe(undefined);
  dfd2.resolve('i am late, sorry');
  scope.$apply();
  expect(scope.myData).not.toBe(undefined);
});
```

You can check what happens when the second response is faster than the first:

```
it('should do this when the other response is faster', function(){
  dfd2.resolve('here is a response');
  // myReq1 is still pending so doSomethingWithBoth() has not yet been called
  scope.$apply();
  expect(scope.myData).toBe(undefined);
  dfd1.resolve('i am late, sorry');
  scope.$apply();
  expect(scope.myData).not.toBe(undefined);
});
```

Or what happens when one of those fails:

```
it('should do this when one response fails', function(){
  dfd1.resolve('blabla');
  dfd2.reject();
  scope.$apply();
  expect(scope.disaster).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use something like where alpha var will have response from 1st call n so on....

```
var promiseAlpha= $http({method: 'GET', url: 'a/pi-one-url', cache: 'true'});
var promiseBeta= $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api-two-url', cache: 'true'});
let promises = {
    alpha: promiseAlpha,
    beta: promiseBeta
}
$q.all(promises).then((values) => {
    console.log(values.alpha); // value alpha
    console.log(values.beta); // value beta
    console.log(values.gamma); // value gamma

    complete();
});
```